# How to this solve very slowly when get request over a thousand data in spring?

Tags: spring, postgresql, rest, tomcat

I am using postgresql as db, tomcat as server. when get request over a 3000 data  in spring, I am getting very slow results with the code below. Adding data to 3 different lists using thread and finally combining these three lists may be a solution, but I think there may be another way to solve this. How do i do this with faster results ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
    List<AccDigiDocFileModel> files = null;
    try {
        files = accountingDataService.listDocuments(datasrvUser, statuses, types, subTypes, stations,
                users);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        response.setErrorCode("DB");
        response.setErrorMessage(e.toString() + "." + e.getMessage());
        LOG.error("::listProcessingFiles response:{}", gson.toJson(response), e);
        return response;
    }

    if (files == null || files.size() == 0) {
        response.setErrorCode("DB");
        response.setErrorMessage("Kayıt bulunamadı!");
        LOG.info("::listProcessingFiles response:{}", gson.toJson(response));
        return response;
    }

    response.setFiles(files);
    response.setResult(true);

    LOG.info("::listProcessingFiles response:{}", gson.toJson(response));

    response.setResult(true);

    return response;
```

Comment: First step is to identify which part is slow. If you suspect the SQL query, then get hold of the query string and use  `explain (analyze, buffers)` to get the execution plan. Then **[edit]** your question and add the plan as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: If you suspect your Java code, then use a profiler to find where the bottleneck is.

Comment: hi , @a_horse_with_no_name I added the correct place to the post in my java code. this is the list to which the data is added.